# how to change android packagename only?

Tags: android, manifest

I have a small android application with this manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.eliran.myapplication" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.eliran.myapplication.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I want alter the package name for testing integration with another andorid app.

However when I change to

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myTest.driver" >
```

I get an error that R class is not found

```
Error:(37, 25) error: package R does not exist
```

how can i fix this, with minimal effort and without changing the package name of each class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio Rename Package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package)

Comment: Minimal effort is to let the IDE do it for you rather than by hand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step #1: Return your `package` attribute to its original value

Step #2: Add `applicationId` to `defaultConfig` in your module's `build.gradle` file to your revised application ID

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        applicationId "com.commonsware.android.espresso"
    }
}
```

This gives your app a separate application ID (the unique identifier for installation purposes) but keeps the package name the same (for `R` generation, etc.).

Comment: I was under the impression that either Gradle took precedence over the Manifest, or they had to match?

Comment: @cricket_007: "I was under the impression that either Gradle took precedence over the Manifest" -- correct. This is why we are changing `build.gradle`, returning the manifest to the original working package name. "or they had to match" -- they do not have to match. Otherwise, `applicationId` would be pointless, as the only valid value is the already-known `package` attribute value.

Comment: Right. But when gradle goes to compile, does it not use that name for classes? Therefore, if that string doesn't match the actual, existing package name, won't it fail?

Comment: @cricket_007: "does it not use that name for classes?" -- it does not use that name for classes. `package` is used for classes. `applicationId` is only for the unique application ID. Pre-Gradle, `package` served both roles, and in the absence of `applicationId`, it still does. `applicationId` overrides `package` just for the unique application ID role, and it has no effect on `R`, `BuildConfig`, data binding, etc. class generation.

Comment: Gotcha... I suppose I could have been linked here, but thanks for the clarification :) https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/new-build-system/applicationid-vs-packagename

Comment: my app opens another app (say app `B`) that checks a whitelist of apps that can open it. Will this work with applicationId ?

Comment: @EladBenda2: Presumably. I do not know how it "checks a whitelist of apps that can open it".

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the applicationID in your build.gradle file

Comment: my app opens another app (say app `B`) that checks a whitelist of apps that can open it. Will this work with applicationId ?